# Jquery-UI Autocomplete Custom Data - Image won't render in autocomplete's dropdown list

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to show a custom data in in autocomplete, a movie poster and movie name (requested via omdb apis). But the image's added dynamically won't display in the browser.

Here's the HTML that get's appended to `ul`

```
<li class="ui-menu-item">
    <div id="ui-id-16" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">
        <img scr="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTUxNzI0MDEzN15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNjc1Njk5._V1_SX300.jpg" class="img-responsve img-thumbnail">
        <h3>The Devil Bat</h3>
        <span>(1940)</span>
   </div>
</li>
```

Here's a complete code on codepen https://codepen.io/rishich/pen/aWOoJy

```
$("input").autocomplete({
autoFocus: true,
delay: 700,
source: function(request, response) {
    suggestions = [];
    console.log(request.term);
    $.getJSON('https://www.omdbapi.com/?type=movie&s=' + request.term, function(data, textStatus) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.Search.length; i++) {
            suggestions.push(data.Search[i]);
        }
        console.log(suggestions);
        response(suggestions);
    });
},
}).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li>")
        .append(
            "<div><img scr='"+item.Poster+"' class='img-responsve img-thumbnail'><h3>"+item.Title+"</h3><span>("+item.Year+")</span></div>"
        )
        .appendTo(ul);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had misspelled `src` attribute as 'scr'.